# How do I change the value of a boolean method in a method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Example :

Class A

```
if (B.example()) {
//  Do something
} 
else {
//  Do something
}
```

Class B

```
public static boolean example{ 
return false; 
} 

public void onPressed() { 
//  Make somebool return true
 }
```

How do I change the value of method example to true in method onPressed?

Comment: your method example is hardcoded to return always false, what are you expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variable can rescue here:

```
class B{
    private boolean pressed; //default is false

    public boolean example{ 
      return pressed; 
    } 

    public void onPressed() { 
      pressed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the boolean permanently true after onPressed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
public class B {
    private boolean pressed = false;

    public boolean isPressed() {
        return pressed;
    }

    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }
}
```

Then you can change values of your boolean by calling `setPressed`. Your code that you have written above will always return true. You need to store the state of your boolean in some kind of variable.